# References for moving and nested grids in models

Tags: models, reference-request

Would anyone know of references that give detailed explanations on concepts such as moving grids and nested grids in models?

Comment: This is probably answerable as a request for a reference to a review article or textbook, but if you want a good answer here you may need to be much more specific.

Comment: http://www2.mmm.ucar.edu/wrf/users/hurricanes/moving_nest.html

Comment: Did you try http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: @SimonW I agree. I just recently heard about nonstationary grids used in models, so I was just looking for something to read up on. I also found that the H*WRF documentation (http://www.emc.ncep.noaa.gov/HWRF/HWRFScientificDocumentation2013.pdf) contains a brief discussion on this as well.

Comment: @IsopycnalOscillation no I was not aware of that site! Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Book:**

Shyy W, Udaykumar HS, Rao MM, Smith RW. Computational Fluid Dynamics with Moving Boundaries. Taylor& Francis: London, 1996.

**Some relevant papers:**

Jin C, Xu K. A unified moving grid gas-kinetic method in Eulerian space for viscous flow comnputation. Journal of Computational Physics 2007; 222:155–175.

Hirt CW, Amsden AA, Cook JL. An arbitrary Lagrangian–Eulerian computing method for all flow speeds. Journal of Computational Physics 1997; 135:203–216.

Piggott M, Pain C, Gorman G, Power P, Goddard A. h, r, and hr adaptivity with applications in numerical ocean modeling. Ocean Modelling 2005; 10:95–113

HuangWZ, Ren Y, Russell RD.Moving mesh methods based on moving mesh partial differential equations. Journal of Computational Physics 1994; 113:279–290.

Miller K, Miller RN. Moving finite element. SIAM Journal of Numerical Analysis 1981; 18:1019–1032.

Dorfi EA, Drury LO. Simple adaptive grids for 1-D initial value problems. Journal of Computational Physics 1987; 69:175–195.

Tang T. Moving mesh methods for computational fluid dynamics. Contemporary Mathematics 2005; 383:141–174.

Tang H, Tang T. Adaptive mesh methods for one- and two-dimensional hyperbolic conservation laws. SIAM Journal of Numerical Analysis 2003; 41(2):487–515.

Tang H, Tang T. Multi-dimensional moving mesh method for shock computations. Contemporary Mathematics 2003; 330:169–183.

---

Adaptive grid concepts have been applied to the [Princeton Ocean Model (POM)](http://www.ccpo.odu.edu/POMWEB/).

**Original Paper for POM:**

[Blumberg, A. F. and G. L. Mellor, A description of a three-dimensional coastal ocean circulation model. Three-Dimensional Coastal ocean Models, edited by N. Heaps, 208 pp., American Geophysical Union., 1987](http://www.stevens-tech.edu/ses/ceoe/fileadmin/ceoe/pdf/alan_publications/AFB032.pdf)

**With adaptive mesh:**

[Hofmeister, Richard, Hans Burchard, and Jean-Marie Beckers. "Non-uniform adaptive vertical grids for 3D numerical ocean models." Ocean Modelling 33.1 (2010): 70-86.](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1463500309002248)

Comment: Can you please comment which flavor of POM uses moving grids? The original variants by Mellor, Blumberg, Oey, etc., do not.

Comment: Moving grids are quite common in atmospheric applications (e.g., WRF), but in ocean applications adaptive meshes are only now being applied. An example that I like is Hofmeister et al., 2010 (http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.ocemod.2009.12.003).

Comment: @milancurcic It seems my notes are wrong. I was looking at old notes from my Ocean Modeling course and it was described as employing a moving grid. Looking at the original paper it clearly does not. The link by @@aretxabaleta shows an implementation of an adaptive/moving grid concept in POM which I will go ahead and include in the answer.